# Eclipse overrides existing project files when importing existing project

Tags: android, eclipse, import, project

I'm working on an existing project from my wd of git.
`.classpath` and `default.properties` files are on the repository.

When I import the project to Eclipse, my `default.properties` is replaced by a `project.properties` (the files' contents are the same) and my `.classpath` is modified.

As I said, these files are on the repository, so my git status is never clean.

Do you know how to force Eclipse using the files provided on the repository *without modifying them* ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default.properties (or project.properties)`

Check out the [changelog](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14) of SDK r14 release:

> default.properties which is the main project’s properties file containing information such as the build platform target and the library dependencies has been renamed project.properties

If someone from your development team still use a version older than r14, better to ask them upgrade to latest Android SDK version on their workstation, as the Android SDK has been changed rapidly since r14 regarding to project property file, library project, external jar dependency structure and etc. It will make development very hard to maintain if developers use different Android SDK version in a team.

If this is not an option in a short term, you should temporarily create and check-in both default.properties and project.properties (with the same contents) for a short period of time, to support old Android version in a short term and give other people time to upgrade their workstation.

---

`.classpath`

It is a very bad practice to commit IDE generated files (.classpath, .project and etc.) into source control. Do you expect .classpath generated from a Windows box has exact the same contents as the one generated from a Mac box? You should add .classpath to your source control ignore list so that it is ignored automatically whenever you commit your project to source control.

When use a source control system, Don't consider too much for every single commit, as long as you provide fully detailed comments. as every single action (add, modified, deleted and etc.) you did on every single file (java source, properties and resources file and etc.) in your project are logged and tracked in source control, in case if something goes wrong, it is quite easy for a sophisticated developer to track the change and revert the project into a normal state. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, it is a *good* idea to commit IDE files into source control, you just have to take some care to make sure they're set up in a machine-agnostic fashion.  Use an Execution Environment instead of a specific named JRE on your machine, use Classpath Variables instead of pointing directly at external jars, etc.  This is why when you check out a plug-in's source project from an Eclipse.org source repository, the .project and .classpath files *are* there-effort's been made so that everyone working on the plug-in doesn't have to recreate these resources themselves.

Comment: @nitind That's what have been done in my case. However what is provided on the repository still needs installations and is not documented. So I have to install stuff manually anyway. In this kind of cases, yorkw's advice makes sense.

Comment: @nitind, if you work in a team, people may use different OS (include different JDK, Android SDK version and etc.) or even different IDE to do their jobs. The .classpath generated by Eclipse is meaningless to NetBeans or intelliJ. Check out the project samples downloaded from Android SDK Manager. it provides a clean project structure template and shows which are the only folders/files a Android Project need to dress up itself as a Android project.

Comment: .project and .classpath are needed to indicate that the project is a Java Project (technically just the former, but the build path is recorded in the latter).