# Eclipse changes project's Android SDK when importing from existing source

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse, or Android is changing my `project.properties` file when I import a project from existing source.

---

When I "export" an existing project from SVN, the `project.properties` file is referencing the correct SDK for that project:

```
# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:7
```

I can see this by opening the file in a text editor. I have not yet imported this as a project into Eclipse.

Then I choose to import it into Eclipse using File...New...Android Project from Existing Source.

Eclipse imports the project, and immediately shows the correct SDK in the project explorer window. Perfect so far.

After a second or so, I can see the SDK change to Android 2.1. Eclipse automatically made the change!

My project.properties file has been updated:

```
# Project target.
target=android-8
```

---

**To summarise:**

- export project from SVN - project.properties points to Google API 7.
- import this into Eclipse - project.properties automatically changes to Android API 8.

I have checked this on a different developer's machine - same behaviour. (i.e. Android SDK Tools 21.0.0 and 21.0.1)

Any ideas?

Comment: this is similar to [Eclipse overrides existing project files when importing existing project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120077/eclipse-overrides-existing-project-files-when-importing-existing-project) - but not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Bug of Eclipse, currently nobody can do anything for it until eclipse developer resolve this bug.

[See Bug Reported Here - Issue 40153: ADT import of project renames project, changes compatibility level](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40153)

(Also this bug is very well written and mentioned there as compaired to asked here...LOL..BTW sorry for your unsolvable problem right now)

Thanks, 
Happy to help.